# Winform's UI is broken depending on the screen ratio, so how can I do this not affect the screen ratio?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried to do that because I was told to do it with DPI, but I don't think it's working.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware); // DPI

var LoadingProgram = new LoadingForm();
LoadingProgram.Show();

var Mainprogram = new MainForm(); 
Mainprogram.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
Mainprogram.Load += (sender, args) => {
    LoadingProgram.Close(); 
};
Mainprogram.Show();
Mainprogram.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
Application.Run();
```

I didn't know the solution, so I asked them to match the same screen ratio or just use the broken UI, but I don't know if this is the right way

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say the winform ui is broken?

Comment: A good tip on asking questions to strangers: 1)What is the *current* behaviour? 2) What is the *expected* behaviour? and 3) What have you done so far?  You have provided us with what you've tried, good! But we still have no idea what it's doing, and what it should be doing... "It's broken" and "It doesn't work" are the enemy of every support person in the world.